# Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment works with TemplateParameterFile but not TemplateParameterObject

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to override some properties in a template parameter file in a powershell script then pass the object to the `Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` cmdlet to test it. The following works;

```
Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -TemplateFile 'template.json' -TemplateParameterFile 'parameters.json'
```

However, it does not work when I load the parameters and pass the object;

```
$params = Get-Content 'parameters.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertPSObjectToHashtable
Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -TemplateFile 'template.json' -TemplateParameterObject $params.parameters
```

The `ConvertPSObjectToHashtable` function is one I got [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002748/hashtables-from-convertfrom-json-have-different-type-from-powershells-built-in-h).

When I run the second command, I get the following error;

```
Code    : InvalidTemplate
Message : Deployment template validation failed: 'The provided value for the template parameter 'location' at line '7' and column '22' is not valid.'.
Details :
```

Why doesn't it accept the parameters object, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test in my lab, I get the same error log with you. The root reason is Azure json template is like below:

```
   "adminUsername": {
      "value": "ghuser"
    },
```

If json template is like below, the function will work.

```
"adminUsername":"ghuser"
```

You also could test in your lab, if you transfer following parameters to `-
 TemplateParameterObject`, it works fine.

```
PS D:\compare> $parms

Name                           Value
----                           -----
adminPassword                  ********
dnsLabelPrefix                 shuitest123
adminUsername                  shui
```

However, your `$params.parameters` is like below:

```
PS D:\compare> $params.parameters

Name                           Value
----                           -----
adminPassword                  {value}
dnsLabelPrefix                 {value}
adminUsername                  {value}
```

What you need to do is convert  Azure parameter json file to `adminUsername:shui` or modify json file like `"adminUsername":"ghuser"`.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for the tips. Unfortunately the `-TemplateParameterObject` is not very well documented. Your suggestion might not work for password that is passed as a reference to a key vault secret. I can always give it a try.