# Can't get keys of an object created from ConvertFrom-Json

Tags: powershell

When an object is created from `ConvertFrom-Json` it doesn't create a "normal" object and is missing `GetEnumerator()` and `keys`.

Here's some demonstration code:

```
$string = '{
  "OBJECT": "SOP10107",
  "OBJECTKEY": "2|OSTD-9999           "
}'

$obj = $string | ConvertFrom-Json

$obj

# no results returned
$obj  | % getEnumerator | % {
  $_.key
  $_.value
}

# no results returned
$obj.keys

$myobj = @{
  "key1" = "val1"
  "key2" = "val2"
}

$myobj

# returns expected result
$myobj | % getEnumerator | % {
  $_.key
  $_.value
}

# returns expected result
$myobj.keys
```

Comment: `$obj.OBJECT` and `$obj.OBJECTKEY`?
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002748/hashtables-from-convertfrom-json-have-different-type-from-powershells-built-in-h) is what you are looking for, I guess.

Comment: Whoops. I missed the link on "this". I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ConvertFrom-JSON` creates a normal object of type `PSCustomObject`, just like `Select-Object` ++.

```
$string = '{
    "OBJECT": "SOP10107",
    "OBJECTKEY": "2|OSTD-9999           "
  }'

$obj = $string | ConvertFrom-Json

#Examine object type and properties
$obj | Get-Member
TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
OBJECT      NoteProperty string OBJECT=SOP10107
OBJECTKEY   NoteProperty string OBJECTKEY=2|OSTD-9999

#Access known properties directly
$obj.OBJECT
SOP10107

$obj.OBJECTKEY
2|OSTD-9999
```

If you want to loop the properties (ex. because you don't known the names), use `$obj.psobject.properties` which returns an array of all properties.

```
#List Name and Value for each property. You can replace Select-Object with `Foreach-Object` to loop through them    
$obj.psobject.properties | Select-Object Name, Value

Name      Value
----      -----
OBJECT    SOP10107
OBJECTKEY 2|OSTD-9999
```

Comment: This works and so did the link Vivek provided. I like your explanation and the solution is a bit easier to understand too.