# Invoke-RestMethod post complex type object as Body not work

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell V4, with the `Invoke-RestMethod` command:

```
Add-Type @"
    using System;

    public class Person{
        public Guid Id {get;set;}
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public int Age {get;set;}
    }
"@
$person = New-Object Person
$person.Age = [int]::(Get-Random -Maximum 99 -Minimum 20)
$person.Name = [string]::("Test" + (Get-Random -Minimum 10 -Maximum 100))

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://localhost:51624/api/personapi" -Method Post -Body $person
```

In the server side,

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post(Person person)
{
    ...

    return Ok();
}
```

The `person` object received in server side is all properties default, for instance the `Age` is `0` and `Name` is `null`. If I change `$person` to `@{Name="..."; Age=11}` then it's ok.

Did I miss something, I want to hold the class definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your casting method seems to be wrong, you should use :

```
$person.Age = [int](Get-Random -Maximum 99 -Minimum 20)
$person.Name = [string]("Test" + (Get-Random -Minimum 10 -Maximum 100))
```

Then [the doc](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849971.aspx) states that the body parameter of invoke-restmethod have to implement  *IDictionary* (typically, a hash table). So you will have to convert your psobject to a **hashtable**.
You can use [the solution given by @Keith Hill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3740403/381149)  for that :

```
$ht2 = @{}
$person.psobject.properties | Foreach { $ht2[$_.Name] = $_.Value }
```

Comment: No, I corrected the casting, it still cannot receive the right value for `Person` object...

Comment: Do you get the proper values if you `$person | fl` right before `Invoke-RestMethod`?

Comment: this is actualy working : `invoke-restmethod http://test/test/ -method post -body @{age=$person.age;name=$person.name}`

Comment: @PeterK Yes, it output the right information as I expected.

Comment: It appears that `Invoke-RestMethod` serializes `$person` as just "Person" (that's the literal sent over the network). You might need to convert the object into a hashtable/dictionary or use `ConvertTo-Json` for a JSON-based REST service.

Comment: @PeterK Thanks, but maybe not for `Json`, I need to convert person object to `hashtable`, do you have any idea how to convert it to `hashtable`with PowerShell build in commonds?

Comment: @Kayasax Thanks a lot, it works. My problem solved, maybe you can enhance your answer, so I can accept :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you posted, the issue is with `[int]::` and `[string]::`. I suppose you wanted to cast

```
$person.Age = [int](Get-Random -Maximum 99 -Minimum 20)
$person.Name = [string]("Test" + (Get-Random -Minimum 10 -Maximum 100))
```

but you were using the double colon operator (static member accessor). Simply removing the double colons fixes the issue.