# Create Hashtable from JSON

Tags: json, powershell

I want to get a JSON representation of a Hashtable such as this:

```
@{Path="C:\temp"; Filter="*.js"}
```

`ConvertTo-Json` results in:

```
{
    "Path":  "C:\\temp",
    "Filter":  "*.js"
}
```

However, if you convert that JSON string back with `ConvertFrom-Json` you don't get a HashTable but a PSCustomObject.

So how can one reliably serialize the above Hashmap?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PSCustomObject to Hashtable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740128/pscustomobject-to-hashtable)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
$json = @{Path="C:\temp"; Filter="*.js"} | ConvertTo-Json

$hashtable = @{}

(ConvertFrom-Json $json).psobject.properties | Foreach { $hashtable[$_.Name] = $_.Value }
```

Adapted from [PSCustomObject to Hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740128/pscustomobject-to-hashtable)

Comment: If the order of items in the hash table is import, then you can create it as `$hashtable = [ordered]@{}`.

Comment: Thank you! This is indeed the shortest and most effective way of converting it.

Answer (score 21):

A little late to the discussion here, but in PowerShell 6 (Core) there is a `-AsHashtable` parameter in [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6).

Comment: Worked for me in Powershell 6.2

Comment: I tried using this but even though I put the flag `AsHashTable` in it still returns a custom object

Comment: simple and easy, great answer

Answer (score 17):

[JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) is available since .NET3.5 (may be installed on XP, included in Win7 and newer), it's several times faster than Convert-FromJSON and it properly parses nested objects, arrays etc.

```
function Parse-JsonFile([string]$file) {
    $text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($file)
    $parser = New-Object Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
    $parser.MaxJsonLength = $text.length
    Write-Output -NoEnumerate $parser.Deserialize($text, [hashtable])
    # To deserialize to a dictionary, use $parser.DeserializeObject($text) instead
}
```

Comment: In PowerShell 5.1 I found that `$parser.DeserializeObject($text)` deserialized to a .NET Dictionary, not a Hashtable  However, the Deserialize method, as opposed to the DeserializeObject method, does deserialize to a Hashtable: `$parser.Deserialize($text, @{}.GetType())` .

Comment: @SimonTewsi You can use `[hashtable]` instead of `@{}.GetType()`.

Answer (score 6):

The answer for this post is a great start, but is a bit naive when you start getting more complex json representations.

The code below will parse nested json arrays and json objects.

```
[CmdletBinding]
function Get-FromJson
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        [string]$Path
    )

    function Get-Value {
        param( $value )

        $result = $null
        if ( $value -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] )
        {
            Write-Verbose "Get-Value: value is PSCustomObject"
            $result = @{}
            $value.psobject.properties | ForEach-Object { 
                $result[$_.Name] = Get-Value -value $_.Value 
            }
        }
        elseif ($value -is [System.Object[]])
        {
            $list = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
            Write-Verbose "Get-Value: value is Array"
            $value | ForEach-Object {
                $list.Add((Get-Value -value $_)) | Out-Null
            }
            $result = $list
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Verbose "Get-Value: value is type: $($value.GetType())"
            $result = $value
        }
        return $result
    }


    if (Test-Path $Path)
    {
        $json = Get-Content $Path -Raw
    }
    else
    {
        $json = '{}'
    }

    $hashtable = Get-Value -value (ConvertFrom-Json $json)

    return $hashtable
}
```

Comment: This does not reconstitute empty lists correctly.  [] should become a 0-length list, not null.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the solution presented in [Converting JSON to a hashtable](https://replicajunction.github.io/2017/07/17/converting-json-to-hashtable/) is closer to the PowerShell 6.0 implementation of [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6)

I tried with several JSON sources and I always got the right hashtable.

```
$mappings = @{
  Letters = (   
      "A",
      "B")
  Numbers        = (
      "1",
      "2",
      "3")
  Yes = 1
  False = "0"
}

# TO JSON 
$jsonMappings = $mappings  | ConvertTo-JSON
$jsonMappings

# Back to hashtable 
# In PowerShell 6.0 would be:
#   | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable
$jsonMappings | ConvertFrom-Json -As hashtable
```

Answer (score 0):

import the code from link here https://4sysops.com/archives/convert-json-to-a-powershell-hash-table/

```
function ConvertTo-Hashtable {
[CmdletBinding()]
[OutputType('hashtable')]
param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
    $InputObject
)

process {
    ## Return null if the input is null. This can happen when calling the function
    ## recursively and a property is null
    if ($null -eq $InputObject) {
        return $null
    }

    ## Check if the input is an array or collection. If so, we also need to convert
    ## those types into hash tables as well. This function will convert all child
    ## objects into hash tables (if applicable)
    if ($InputObject -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable] -and $InputObject -isnot [string]) {
        $collection = @(
            foreach ($object in $InputObject) {
                ConvertTo-Hashtable -InputObject $object
            }
        )

        ## Return the array but don't enumerate it because the object may be pretty complex
        Write-Output -NoEnumerate $collection
    } elseif ($InputObject -is [psobject]) { ## If the object has properties that need enumeration
        ## Convert it to its own hash table and return it
        $hash = @{}
        foreach ($property in $InputObject.PSObject.Properties) {
            $hash[$property.Name] = ConvertTo-Hashtable -InputObject $property.Value
        }
        $hash
    } else {
        ## If the object isn't an array, collection, or other object, it's already a hash table
        ## So just return it.
        $InputObject
    }
}
```

}
We can then call this function via pipeline:
$json | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-HashTable

Answer (score -2):

you can write a function convert psobject to hashtable.

I wrote a answer here:[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52656886/4430265)

Comment: Please post your code as part of the answer instead of a link, as links may go down in the future

Comment: The link lacks a useful description/title (well there is non).