# Easy way to reference JSON arrays

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-core

I am finding working with JSON to be much more complex than in other scripting languages, so I can't help but think I am missing an easier way to do this. Given this `json.txt` file:

```json
{"key":"value","key1":"a string with       lots    of    spaces"}
```

I have this working PowerShell code:

```bsh
$SECRETS_FILE = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\json.txt'
$data = Get-Content -Raw -Path $SECRETS_FILE | ConvertFrom-Json
$data.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_.Name -eq "key") {
    $value = $_.Value
    cli_cmd value=$value
  }
}
```

And I want to do something like this:

```bsh
$SECRETS_FILE = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\json.txt'
$data = Get-Content -Raw -Path $SECRETS_FILE | ConvertFrom-Json
cli_cmd value=$data["key"]
```

I have seen many code examples online of referencing keys within a PowerShell object using the `$object["key"]` format, but in my case I get nothing. In the above example, `$data["key"]` returns null, `$data.keys` returns null. I'm at a loss. I can't believe the only way to reference keys within an array is to loop through the entire array doing string matches.

Comment: While I've closed this as a duplicate, I want to point out that since you tagged the question with [tag:powershell-core], you should look at [this newer answer in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48992740/3905079), which shows that in PowerShell Core (v6+), an `-AsHashtable` parameter was added to `ConvertFrom-Json` which does exactly what you want.

Comment: I did try that, and it does not appear to do what I want. `$data["key"]` translates to `"System.Collections.Hashtable[key]"` rather than the value of that key

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior. In PowerShell Core, this works as expected: `$data = '{"key":"value","key1":"a string with       lots    of    spaces"}' | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable ; $data["key"]`

Comment: @DrStrangepork Looks like PowerShell interprets `value=$data["key"]` as a string. Try `$value = $data['key']; cli_cmd value=$value` or `cli_cmd "value=$($data['key'])"` instead.

Comment: Ansgar Wiechers' comment is correct - `cli_cmd "value=$($data['key'])"` fixed the problem. I'd like this question reopened so I can give them credit.

Comment: What I outlined is a common problem with the interpolation of variables in strings. Even if someone re-opened the question it would still be a duplicate, though perhaps of a different question (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9196525/1630171)).