# How do I define hash tables with protected values using the VariableDefinitions section in PowerShell JEA session configuration files?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, remoting, jea

When defining "private global" variables to be used with functions and scripts in JEA sessions using `New-PSSessionConfigurationFile`, I noticed that I'm only able to create string variables.

Is there any way to define other types of objects in the `VariableDefinitions` section?

The following definitions

```
VariableDefinitions @(
  @{ Name = 'Test'   ; Value = 'blah' }
  @{ Name = 'Integer'; Value = 13 }
  @{ Name = 'Array'  ; Value = @(1,2,3,4,'b') }

  @{
    Name  = 'Hash'
    Value = @{
      Hash1 = '1'
      Hash2 = '2'
    }
  }

)
```

will result in (if allowing Invoke-Command in Visible Cmdlets of course)

```
> Invoke-Command {$Test}
blah

> Invoke-Command {$Integer}
13

> Invoke-Command {$Array}
System.Object[]

> Invoke-Command {$Hash}
System.Collections.Hashtable
```

At first, I got confused, as the result indicated some kind of object was returned. But on closer inspection, it turned out to be the original object type name that was returned as a string.

```
> Invoke-Command {$Array -is [string]}
True

> Invoke-Command {$Hash -is [string]}
True

> Invoke-Command {$Integer -is [string]}
True
```

So it would seem that the only objects possible to define using `VariableDefinitions` is variables of type `[string]`.

But is there a way of defining other types of variables using `VariableDefinitions`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's a no-brainer spotted by a colleague of mine.
Why not just use JSON-notation for the parts that isn't strings?

This will still require some work on the receiving end, but far less as specified in my previous suggestion.

```
VariableDefinitions @(
  @{ Name = 'Test'   ; Value = 'blah' }

  @{
    Name  = 'TestHash'
    Value = '{
      "Hash1" : "1"
      "Hash2" : "2"
    }'
  }

)
```

Accessing the variables will result in

```
> Invoke-Command {$Test}
blah

> Invoke-Command {$TestHash}
{
  "Hash2" : "2"
  "Hash1" : "1"
}
```

This can of course be converted to PowerShell dataformat using `ConvertFrom-Json`, with one little caveat.

```
> Invoke-Command {$TestHash | ConvertFrom-Json}

Hash2 Hash1
----- -----
2     1
```

To bring it back to a hash value we need to use `ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashTable`. And if using Windows PowerShell 5.1, this can be accomplished with

```
> Invoke-Command {
  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web.Extensions # Might not be needed
  $Parser = New-Object Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer

  $Parser.Deserialize($TestHash, [hashtable])
}

Name            Value
----            -----
Hash1           1
Hash2           2
```

See [Create Hashtable from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495248/create-hashtable-from-json)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for not being able to define hash variables in `VariableDefintions`, might be to define all the key pairs as separate string variables and then construct the hash variable in each function/script where it is to be used...

I don't fancy this solution, but it's doable.

##### 1. Define the simple variables

```
VariableDefinitions @(
  @{ Name = 'Cars1'   ; Value = 'MyCar'   }
  @{ Name = 'Cars1Val'; Value = 'Volvo'   }

  @{ Name = 'Cars2'   ; Value = 'YourCar' }
  @{ Name = 'Cars2Val'; Value = 'Tesla'   }
}
```

##### 2. Define the helper function in all placec needed

This helper function will make it somewhat easier to use hash variables.
Do **NOT** place it as a standalone function in `FunctionDefinitions` as that would expose the feature to the JEA-user.

```
function New-HashVariable {
<#
.NOTES
  Looks for simple string variables already defined in pairs, like

  $VarNameX - $VarNameXVal
  $VarNameY - $VarNameYVal

  and creates a hashtable, $VarName, containing the labeled
  values provided in the simple string variables.
#>

  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (
    [string]$Name,
    [switch]$ValueOnly
  )

  Set-Variable $Name -Value @{} -Force
  $KeyIndex = 0

  Get-Variable -Name "$($Name)?" -ValueOnly | foreach {#hash value pair found
    $KeyIndex++

    Set-Variable $Name -Value (#add a value pair
      (Get-Variable $Name -ValueOnly) + @{
        (Get-Variable -Name "$($Name)$KeyIndex" -ValueOnly) =
        (Get-Variable -Name "$($Name)$($KeyIndex)Val" -ValueOnly)
      }
    )#end extend hash table

  }#end foreach value pair

  if ($ValueOnly) {
    return Get-Variable $Name -ValueOnly
  }

  return Get-Variable $Name

}
```

##### 3. Create the hash variable wherever needed...

```
Invoke-Command {
  <define helper function>

  $Cars = New-HashVariable 'Cars' -ValueOnly
}
```

Adding `$cars` at the end of the Invoke-Command will result in

```
> $cars

Name      Value
----      -----
YourCar   Tesla
MyCar     Volvo
```

You could of course declare the hash variables normally in any script defined in `ScriptsToProcess`, but that won't keep the hash values hidden.

The same goes for using `New-HashVariable` in a script. In that case you'd need to delete it after usage in the script or else it will be available in the JEA interactive console session.