# PowerShell: how to populate hashtable automatically from get-aduser

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, hashtable

using the following command, I will get the entire user detail from active directory. However, I want all the details populate into hashtable. How to do this.

```
get-aduser User1234 -server myDomain -properties *
```

So, if I use the following, I will get this:

```
$table1 = get-aduser User1234 -server myDomain -properties *
$table1.GetType()
```

Result:
BaseType is                                  Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount

It is not hashtable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740128/pscustomobject-to-hashtable

Comment: @Matt, That does it. However, the subject name is little off... Anyway, it seems the answer is really about the `$OneObj.PSObject.Properties.Name` and `$OneObj.PSObject.Properties.Value` as default header for the PSObject.