# Extract word from powershell output Search-String

Tags: powershell

Hi All I'm trying to extract a word from a text output.  It should be pretty easy but I've already spent so much time on it.  Right now I can extract the line but not just the word.

For example

```
w32tm /query /status | Select-String -pattern "CMOS"
```

outputs the line
"Source: Local CMOS Clock"

I only want to extract "Local CMOS Clock"

```
$var1=w32tm /query /status | Select-String -pattern "CMOS"

$var2=($var1 -split ':')[1] | Out-String
```

I was able to come up with the above it seems to work I'm not sure if there's a better way, I'm trying to evaluate it through a true/false seem to always pass as true though
For example

```
if($var2 = "Local CMOS Clock"){
Write-Output "True";
}Else{
Write-Output "False";
}
```

Always true: even when the condition is wrong

thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, this can be confusing to start with, but `=` is an assignment operator in PowerShell, so this means you're setting `$var2` to equal `"Local CMOS Clock"` and asking if that's true. Replace `=` with `-eq`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that bit `if ($var2 = "Local CMOS Clock")` becomes `if($var2 -eq "Local CMOS Clock")`

Comment: thank you for feedback
Seem now it is evaluating as false now - I'm thinking $var2 is not being considered a string

Comment: It's still a string, check by running `$var2.GetType()`. Try `if ($var2.Trim() -eq "Local CMOS Clock")`, this will remove leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: YES $var2.Trim() worked
thank you for your feedback!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of your motives, but here's a cleaner way to get to the answer you're looking for:

#### Build a PSObject containing the output

The PSObject will contain the output of w32tm. The code works by piping the command output through a loop, at the beginning we make a HashTable and then this is used to build a PowerShell object which is easier to manipulate:

```
# Pipe the w32tm command through a foreach
# Build a hashtable object containing the keys
# $_ represents each entry in the command output, which is then split by ':'
$w32_obj = w32tm /query /status | ForEach-Object -Begin {$w32_dict = @{}} -Process {
    # Ignore blank entries
    if ($_ -ne '') {
        $fields = $_ -split ': '
        # This part sets the elements of the w32_dict. 
        # Some rows contain more than one colon, 
        # so we combine all (except 0) the split output strings together using 'join'
        $w32_dict[$fields[0]] = $($fields[1..$($fields.Count)] -join ':').Trim()
    }
} -End {New-Object psobject -Property $w32_dict}
```

#### View the PSObject

Simply run this to display the new PSObject that has been created:

```
$w32_obj
```

#### Now check the 'Source'

Now we can ask for the 'Source' object from `$w32_obj` by using the dot-notation: `$w32_obj.Source`:

```
if($w32_obj.Source -eq "Local CMOS Clock"){
Write-Output "True";
}Else{
Write-Output "False";
}
```

#### Further reading

This shows the conversion from HashTable to PSobject and vice-versa

[PSCustomObject to Hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740128/pscustomobject-to-hashtable)

Comment: Hey Thanks for this as I think it is much better thank you for help with the new code. I am trying to create a custom solarwind monitor.   trying to avoid using winrm but I think winrm may be the only way with what I am trying to do since w32tm doesn't support a credential flag. Unless there is another way to pull this info with powershell. still searching

Answer (score 0):

here's yet another way to get the False/True from w32tm. my system does not have "cmos" in the output, so i use 'system clock', but the idea will work for your situation.

```
[bool]((w32tm /query /status) -match 'system clock')
```

the above returns a `$True` on my system. that seems a tad more direct than the method you used. [*grin*]

take care,
lee