# Find and Replace Nested JSON Values with Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, .net-core, azure-devops

I have an `appsettings.json` file that I would like to transform with a PowerShell script in a VSTS release pipeline PowerShell task. (BTW I'm deploying a netstandard 2 Api to IIS).  The JSON is structured like the following:

```json
{
    "Foo": {
        "BaseUrl": "http://foo.url.com",
        "UrlKey": "12345"
    },
    "Bar": {
        "BaseUrl": "http://bar.url.com"
    },
    "Blee": {
        "BaseUrl": "http://blee.url.com"
    }
}
```

I want to replace BaseUrl and, if it exists, the UrlKey values in each section which are Foo, Bar and Blee.  (Foo:BaseUrl, Foo:UrlKey, Bar:BaseUrl, etc.)

I'm using the following JSON structure to hold the new values:

```json
{ 
    "##{FooUrl}":"$(FooUrl)", 
    "##{FooUrlKey}":"$(FooUrlKey)",
    "##{BarUrl}":"$(BarUrl)",
    "##{BleeUrl}":"$(BleeUrl)"
}
```

So far I have the following script:

```bsh
# Get file path
$filePath = "C:\mywebsite\appsettings.json"

# Parse JSON object from string
$jsonString = "$(MyReplacementVariablesJson)"
$jsonObject = ConvertFrom-Json $jsonString

# Convert JSON replacement variables object to HashTable
$hashTable = @{}
foreach ($property in $jsonObject.PSObject.Properties) {
    $hashTable[$property.Name] = $property.Value
}

# Here's where I need some help

# Perform variable replacements
foreach ($key in $hashTable.Keys) {
    $sourceFile = Get-Content $filePath
    $sourceFile -replace $key, $hashTable[$key] | Set-Content $filePath
    Write-Host 'Replaced key' $key 'with value' $hashTable[$key] 'in' $filePath
}
```

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you defining your replacement values as a JSON string? That's just going to make your life more miserable. If you're defining the values in your script anyway just define them as hashtables right away:

```
$newUrls = @{
    'Foo'  = 'http://newfoo.example.com'
    'Bar'  = 'http://newbaz.example.com'
    'Blee' = 'http://newblee.example.com'
}

$newKeys = @{
    'Foo' = '67890'
}
```

Even if you wanted to read them from a file you could make that file a PowerShell script containing those hashtables and dot-source it. Or at least define the values as lists of `key=value` lines in text files, which can easily be turned into hashtables:

```
$newUrls = Get-Content 'new_urls.txt' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-StringData
$newKeys = Get-Content 'new_keys.txt' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

Then iterate over the top-level properties of your input JSON data and replace the nested properties with the new values:

```
$json = Get-Content $filePath | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($name in $json.PSObject.Properties) {
    $json.$name.BaseUrl = $newUrls[$name]
    if ($newKeys.ContainsKey($name)) {
        $json.$name.UrlKey = $newKeys[$name]
    }
}
$json | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $filePath
```

Note that if your actual JSON data has more than 2 levels of hierarchy you'll need to tell `ConvertTo-Json` via the parameter `-Depth` how many levels it's supposed to convert.

---

Side note: piping the `Get-Content` output through `Out-String` is required because `ConvertFrom-Json` expects JSON input as a single string, and using `Out-String` makes the code work with all PowerShell versions. If you have PowerShell v3 or newer you can simplify the code a little by replacing `Get-Content | Out-String` with `Get-Content -Raw`.

Comment: I am getting "The property 'BaseUrl' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."  How do I check to make sure the name has a property of BaseUrl?  For example Foo has BaseUrl but Baz does not.

Comment: For something like that you'd need to enumerate the properties of `$json.$name`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Ansgar for your detailed answer, which helped me a great deal. Ultimately, after having no luck iterating over the top-level properties of my input JSON data, I settled on the following code:

```
$json = (Get-Content -Path $filePath) | ConvertFrom-Json

    $json.Foo.BaseUrl = $newUrls["Foo"]
    $json.Bar.BaseUrl = $newUrls["Bar"]
    $json.Blee.BaseUrl = $newUrls["Blee"]

    $json.Foo.Key = $newKeys["Foo"]

$json | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $filePath
```

I hope this can help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

To update values of keys at varying depth in the json/config file, you can pass in the key name using "." between the levels, e.g. AppSettings.Setting.Third to represent:

```
{
    AppSettings = {
        Setting = {
            Third = "value I want to update"
        }
    }
}
```

To set the value for multiple settings, you can do something like this:

```
$file = "c:\temp\appSettings.json"

# define keys and values in hash table
$settings = @{
    "AppSettings.SettingOne" = "1st value"
    "AppSettings.SettingTwo" = "2nd value"
    "AppSettings.SettingThree" = "3rd value"
    "AppSettings.SettingThree.A" = "A under 3rd"
    "AppSettings.SettingThree.B" = "B under 3rd"
    "AppSettings.SettingThree.B.X" = "Z under B under 3rd"
    "AppSettings.SettingThree.B.Y" = "Y under B under 3rd"
}

# read config file
$data = Get-Content $file -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

# loop through settings
$settings.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    $key = $_.Key
    $value = $_.Value

    $command = "`$data.$key = $value"
    Write-Verbose $command

    # update value of object property
    Invoke-Expression -Command $command
}
        
$data | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 | Out-File $file -Encoding "UTF8"
```

Answer (score 1):

This method deep clones a hashtable but overrides keys which you provide in a separate object. It uses recursion to handle nesting. If you're using PS7 `ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable` is helpful but if you're stuck on PS5 like me you can see another answer of mine for [converting the PSObject to a hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76738910/5339918).

The only downside I've encountered so far is I don't have a decent way of updating an key within an array of objects but I figured I'd share it anyway if I don't get around to or can't find a solution to that.

I dislike the idea of using numeric indexing like `foo.0.bar` since if the someone inserts another object at the start of the array that statement would update the wrong value so my ideal solution would perform a lookup on another key within the object.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS

Given two hashtables this function overrides values of the first using the second.

.NOTES

This function is based on Kevin Marquette's Get-DeepClone
function as documented below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable?view=powershell-7.3#deep-copies

.EXAMPLE
# Use nested hashtable to apply updates.

$Settings = @{
    foo = "foo"
    bar = "bar"
    one = @{
        two = "three"
    }
}

$Updates = @{
    foo = 'fubar'
    one = @{
        two = 'four'
    }
}

$Clone = Update-Hashtable $Settings $Updates
$Clone

.EXAMPLE

# Use flattened hashtable to apply updates.

$Settings = @{
    foo = "foo"
    bar = "bar"
    one = @{
        two = "three"
    }
}

$StringData = @"
foo=fubar
one.two=five
"@
$Updates = $StringData | ConvertFrom-StringData

$Clone = Update-Hashtable $Settings $Updates -UpdatesAreFlattened
$Clone
#>
function Update-Hashtable {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Object] $InputObject,
        [Object] $Updates = @{},
        [Switch] $UpdatesAreFlattened,
        
        # This parameter is used to keep track of our position
        # in a nested object during recursion.
        [Parameter(DontShow)]
        [String] $Keychain
    )
    process {
        if ($InputObject -is [Hashtable]) {
            $Clone = @{}
            
            foreach ($Key in $InputObject.Keys) {
                # Track our nested level by appending keys.
                $Keychain = if ($KeyChain) { "$Keychain.$Key" } else { $Key }

                # Because flattened updates don't keep track our nested level, use the
                # keychain to index it instead of the current key.
                $UpdateKey = if ($UpdatesAreFlattened) { $Keychain } else { $Key }
                $UpdateValue = $Updates.$UpdateKey

                if ($Updates -and $UpdateValue) {
                    $Clone.$Key = $UpdateValue
                } else {
                    # Unflattened updates provide the nested object while flattened updates are single
                    # level so pass the full object
                    $ForwardUpdates = if ($UpdatesAreFlattened) { $Updates } else { $Updates.$Key }
                    $Clone.$Key = Update-Hashtable $InputObject.$Key $ForwardUpdates $Keychain -UpdatesAreFlattened:$UpdatesAreFlattened
                }
                $KeyChain = $null  # Reset the chain.
            }
            return $Clone
        } else {
            return $InputObject
        }
    }
}
```