# How to convert PSCustomObject with additional props to a custom class

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, pscustomobject

Is there a neat way to convert a `PSCustomObject` to a custom class as a function parameter in PowerShell 5.1?
The custom object contains additional properties.

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```bsh
class MyClass {
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string]$PropA
}

$input = [pscustomobject]@{
    PropA          = 'propA';
    AdditionalProp = 'additionalProp';
}

function DuckTypingFtw {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline)] [MyClass] $myObj
    )
    'Success!'
}

DuckTypingFtw $input
```

Unfortunately, instead of `Success!`, I'm getting:

> DuckTypingFtw : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter
>   'myObj'. Cannot convert value "@{PropA=propA; 
>   AdditionalProp=additionalProp}" to type "MyClass". Error: "Cannot
>   convert the "@{PropA=propA; AdditionalProp=additionalProp}" value of
>   type "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to type "MyClass"."
>   At C:\temp\tmp.ps1:23 char:15
>   + DuckTypingFtw $input
>   +               ~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [DuckTypingFtw], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,DuckTypingFtw

If I comment out the `AdditionalProp`, everything works fine.

Basically, what I want to achieve, is to return an object from one function and pass it to a second function, at the same time ensuring that the second function's param has all expected properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create a constructor for the MyClass class that accepts an pscustomobject and pass through the property then that should work:

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass([pscustomobject]$object){
        $this.PropA = $object.PropA
    }
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string]$PropA
}

$input = [pscustomobject]@{
    PropA          = 'propA';
    AdditionalProp = 'additionalProp';
}

function DuckTypingFtw {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline)] [MyClass] $myObj
    )
    'Success!'
}

DuckTypingFtw $input
```

edit:
If you want to also use MyClass somewhere else, add a default constructor for MyClass like:

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass() { } 
    MyClass([pscustomobject]$object){
        $this.PropA = $object.PropA
    }
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string]$PropA
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility, besides the solution mentioned by @JacobStruiksma, is to introduce an **implicit or explicit cast operator** (the names of the operators are case-sensitive!):

```
class MyClass {
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string]$PropA
    MyClass() {} # if a parameterless constructor is required elsewhere
    MyClass([string]$PropA) {
        $this.PropA = $PropA
    }
    hidden static [MyClass] op_Implicit([PSObject]$myObj) {
        return [MyClass]::new($myObj.PropA)
    }
#   hidden static [MyClass] op_Explicit([PSObject]$myObj) {
#       return [MyClass]::new($myObj.PropA)
#   }
}

$myInput = [pscustomobject]@{
    PropA          = 'propA';
    AdditionalProp = 'additionalProp';
}

function DuckTypingFtw {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline)] [MyClass] $myObj
    )
    'Success!'
}

DuckTypingFtw $myInput
```

[<del>In your case, both</del>Both] operators work identically. [<del>In other cases, op_Explicit offers a bit more control, but at the expense of typing.</del>]

By the way, $Input is as system variable [that should be considered read-only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.3).

[<del>**Edit 1:** PowerShell's own conversion function using a class constructor corresponds to op_Explicit.</del>]

**Edit 2:** According to @Vopel 's comment, there doesn't seem to be any difference in the behavior of both operators in a PowerShell script.

Comment: Can I ask when op_Explicit is different from op_Implicit as far as PowerShell classes are concerned? I can find info about the difference in C# but considering in PowerShell you always use the explicit syntax, I'm not sure how it could ever matter for classes.

Comment: @Vopel Sorry for not answering for a long time! I've overseen your question. As far as I understand, PowerShell and C# may behave similarly. The example shows an implicit casting: `DuckTypingFtw $myInput`. If only op_Explicit would be defined, one would have to do `DuckTypingFtw [MyClass]$myInput`.

Comment: Seems the examples you gave work in either case. I think PowerShell just makes everything implicit.

Comment: @Vopel: You're right! I recalled noticing differences in one particular situation (i.e. using `op_Implicit` required a casting where `op_Explicit` did not). However, I cannot reproduce this behavior. So I must have misinterpreted something then. I will amend my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

In your code you define two properties for the custom object but one for the class. That's why you need either:

- to add `AdditionalProp` in your class
- to remove `AdditionalProp` from your PsCustomObject

The conversion is not possible by design.

Comment: Yes, that's the trivia, and as I said: "If I comment out the AdditionalProp, everything works fine.". I still hope that there is a way - a custom converter perhaps?

Comment: You can define a function like `Map-Property` that accepts both a class and pscustomobject and use reflection on them, possibly via `Get-Member` and iterate through properties. So that you can match them and ignore the ones which do not "map" properly.

Comment: Yes, well, but the `DuckTypingFtw` is a public API, so I can't expect that consumers would call `Map-Property`. It needs to be transparent...

Comment: It seems like the only way is returning an instance of class `MyClass` and never use the `pscustomobject`.