# PowerShell: Get Key and Value from Json

Tags: json, powershell, convertfrom-json

I have the following Json:

```
{
    "variable1" : "variable2"
}
```

I won't know what the values for `variable1` and `variable2` are. I need to get them from the Json, presumably using two separate commands that use `ConvertFrom-Json` in some way. They should be returned in plaintext format, not any PS Custom Object or anything like that.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala How to get each of the values for variable1 and variable2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export the keys and values as plain text using `Out-File`.

```
$json=@'
{
    "variable1": "variable2",
    "variable3": "variable4",
    "variable5": "variable6"
}
'@|ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable

PS /~> $json

Name                           Value
----                           -----
variable3                      variable4
variable5                      variable6
variable1                      variable2

PS /~> $json.Keys
variable3
variable5
variable1

PS /~> $json.Values
variable4
variable6
variable2
```

Edit:

Credit to @Vivere, did not know `-AsHashTable` was introduced on PS Core. Supposing the test is performed on PS 5.1 here is how to get the same result. If the JSON has more depth check out the link provided by him on comment below.

```
PS /~> $json=@'
{
    "variable1": "variable2",
    "variable3": "variable4",
    "variable5": "variable6"
}
'@|ConvertFrom-Json

PS /~> $json.psobject.Properties.Name
variable1
variable3
variable5

PS /~> $json.psobject.Properties.Name|%{$json.$_}
variable2
variable4
variable6
```

Comment: Note that `-AsHashtable` is introduced in PowerShell core if I'm not mistaken. For Desktop edition 5.1 this won't work. `ConvertFrom-Json` will return a `PSCustomObject` and making it a hashtable is troublesome depending on the depth. This part is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740128/pscustomobject-to-hashtable).

Comment: @Vivere thanks for pointing this out, I did not know this, I barely use `ConvertFrom-Json`. I added an edit with credit to your comment :)