# How to convert nested JSON into hashtable in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to convert JSON into hashtable in 5.1 version of Powershell. But the output is coming as an object again for FieldMapping Key. Can we get the key value pairs for FieldMapping key?

We have ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable in 7.1 version . Ideally trying to get the same o/p in 5.1 as well. What can I try next?

**My json:**

```
$json = '[
 
                              {
 
                                  "EntityType": "IP",
 
                                  "FieldMapping":  [
 
                                                       {
 
                                                           "ColumnName":  "FileHashCustomEntity"
                                                            "Identifier":  "Address"
                                                           
 
                                                       }
 
                                                   ]
 
                              }
 
                          ]'
```

**My code:**

```
$entities = $json | ConvertFrom-Json 
$ht2 = @{}
$hash = $entities.psobject.properties | Foreach { $ht2[$_.Name] = $_.Value }
echo $ht2
```

**My output:**

```
Key   : EntityType
Value : IP
Name  : EntityType


Key   : FieldMapping
Value : {@{ColumnName=FileHashCustomEntity; Identifier=Address}}
Name  : FieldMapping
```

**Expected output:**

```
 Key   : EntityType
 Value : IP
 Name  : EntityType


 Key   : FieldMapping
 Value : {FileHashCustomEntity}
 Name  : FieldMapping
```

Comment: Try : Foreach { $ht2[$_.Name] = $_.Value | Format-Table}

Comment: Hi jdweng.. tried using the above suggested code. But got o/p in this format: Key   : EntityType
Value : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
Name  : EntityType


Key   : FieldMapping
Value : {Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData, 
        Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData, 
        Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData, 
        Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData…}
Name  : FieldMapping

Comment: You need to do this recursively and treat arrays specifically. If this works for you, we can close as duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34383413/7571258

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're ending up with a top-level hashtable containing custom objects as entries - what you need to do is convert *every object* in the resulting object hierarchy *recursively*.

Here's a simple function that does that:

```
function Convert-PSCToHashTable
{
  param(
    $InputObject, 
    [int]$Depth = 5
  )

  if($Depth -gt 0){
    if($InputObject -is [System.Collections.IList]){
      return @($InputObject |ForEach-Object {Convert-PSCToHashTable $_ -Depth ($Depth - 1)})
    }

    if($InputObject.psobject.BaseObject -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]){
      $ht = @{}
      foreach($prop in $InputObject.psobject.Properties){
        $ht[$prop.Name] = Convert-PSCToHashTable $prop.Value -Depth ($Depth - 1)
      }
      return $ht
    }
  }

  return $InputObject
}
```

Now you can do:

```
$object = ConvertFrom-Json $json
$hashtable = Convert-PSCToHashTable $object

$hashtable['FieldMapping']['ColumnName'] # "FileHashCustomEntity"
```

Comment: tried to use the above function to convert json to hashtable. I'm trying to send this hashtable to  the following command. New-AzSentinelAlertRule   -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -WorkspaceName $WorkspaceName  -QueryFrequency 1:00:00   -QueryPeriod 1:00:00 -DisplayName "TesS-2"   -Kind Scheduled   -Query "SecurityAlert | where TimeGenerated == '99'"   -Severity Low    -TriggerOperator GreaterThan -TriggerThreshold 10 -EntityMapping $hashtable

Comment: Facing this error :  Invalid data model. [: Invalid length of '0' for 'EntityMappings'. 'EntityMappings' length should be between '1' and '5']

Comment: How can I send this hashtable to EntityMapping parameter ? Can you please help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

This works.  Included debug statements so you can see how the data is organized

```
$json = @" 
[
 
                              {
 
                                  "EntityType": "IP",
 
                                  "FieldMapping":  [
 
                                                       {
 
                                                           "ColumnName":  "FileHashCustomEntity",
                                                            "Identifier":  "Address"
                                                           
 
                                                       }
 
                                                   ]
 
                              }
 
                          ]
"@
$entities = $json | ConvertFrom-Json 
$entities
$ht2 = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
$newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName EntityType -NotePropertyValue $entities.EntityType
foreach($property in $entities.FieldMapping)
{
$property | Format-Table
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName ColumnName -NotePropertyValue $property.ColumnName  
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Identifier -NotePropertyValue $property.Identifier
 
}
$ht2.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null

$ht2 | Format-Table
```

Comment: This outputs an ArrayList of PsCustomObjects. Not a Hashtable at all as the OP wants